# How to merge 2 JSON Arrays in Groovy?

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

Trying to merge 2 Json arrays into 1 in groovy.

```
def branchTags = new JsonBuilder()
    branchTags branches, { String branch ->
        tag branch
        type 'b'
    }
    println(branchTags.toString()) 
    //generates [{"tag":"Branch","type":"b"},{"tag":"Branch1","type":"b"}]

    def releaseTags = new JsonBuilder()
    releaseTags releases, {String release ->
        tag release
        type 'r'
    }
    println(releaseTags.toString())
    //generates [{"tag":"Release","type":"r"},{"tag":"Rel1","type":"r"}]

    /*def newTags = new JsonBuilder()
    branchTags.each {k,v -> newTags.}*/
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def input = slurper.parseText(branchTags.toString())
    def res = slurper.parseText(releaseTags.toString())

    def joined = [input, res].flatten()
    println joined.toString()
    //this generates [{"tag":"Branch","type":"b"},{"tag":"Branch1","type":"b"}][{"tag":"Release","type":"r"},{"tag":"Rel1","type":"r"}]
```

I need:

```
[
   {"tag":"Branch","type":"b"},
   {"tag":"Branch1","type":"b"}, 
   {"tag":"Release","type":"r"},
   {"tag":"Rel1","type":"r"}
]
```

TIA,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your case after you parsed json you have two arrays.

just use `+` to concatenate two arrays into one

```
import groovy.json.*

def branchTags = '[{"tag":"Branch","type":"b"},{"tag":"Branch1","type":"b"}]'
def releaseTags = '[{"tag":"Release","type":"r"},{"tag":"Rel1","type":"r"}]'

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def bArr = slurper.parseText(branchTags)
def rArr = slurper.parseText(releaseTags)

def res = bArr+rArr

println new JsonBuilder(res).toString()
```